# React Native Fails when I Select Command Line tools in Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native, rubygems, cocoapods

So I've been batteling with this issue for few days now, when I initialize an RN project before selecting Command Line tools the initialization fails when installing dependencies and after installing Gem Ruby, when I select the Command Line tools the initialization fails at Installing Gem Ruby.

I tried reinstalling Ruby, GCC, and thought at some point the issue was with gcc4.2 or the lack of it!

I got to a point where I select the CLT hit the npx react-native init command, wait for Gem ruby to finish and reset the CLT using `xcode-select -r` and it works,

I am about to lose my mind, what's wrong with my machine!

macOS 12.6.7 (Fresh Install)
Xcode 12.2 (Fresh Install)

> Installing CocoaPods fail when I have CLT selected Log #1

```
current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20230709-835-1hev0kq.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --enable-system-libffi
    --disable-system-libffi
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `block in try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `with_werror'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1109:in `block in have_header'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1108:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:10:in `system_libffi_usable?'
    from extconf.rb:42:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

> Installing CocoaPods fail when I have CLT selected Log #2

```
package configuration for libffi is not found
"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin21 -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS -DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib -L. -L/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/c188b140-2ff3-11ed-a7e5-ca9c01dc79de/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.6.Internal.sdk/usr/local/lib     -lruby.2.6   "
In file included from conftest.c:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: note: did not find header 'config.h' in framework 'ruby' (loaded from '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks')
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

> Creating React Native App fail when I have CLT selected Log #1

```
                Welcome to React Native!                
                 Learn once, write anywhere               

✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing Ruby Gems
error Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching rexml 3.2.5
Installing rexml 3.2.5
Fetching CFPropertyList 3.0.6
Installing CFPropertyList 3.0.6
Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.2.2
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.2.2
Fetching i18n 1.14.1
Installing i18n 1.14.1
Fetching minitest 5.18.1
Installing minitest 5.18.1
Fetching tzinfo 2.0.6
Installing tzinfo 2.0.6
Fetching zeitwerk 2.6.8
Installing zeitwerk 2.6.8
Fetching activesupport 6.1.7.4
Installing activesupport 6.1.7.4
Fetching public_suffix 4.0.7
Installing public_suffix 4.0.7
Fetching addressable 2.8.4
Installing addressable 2.8.4
Fetching httpclient 2.8.3
Installing httpclient 2.8.3
Fetching json 2.6.3
Installing json 2.6.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/Users/wj/Projects/test/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-2.6.3/ext/json/ext/generator
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20230710-7170-ia3mfb.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/wj/Projects/test/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-2.6.3 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/wj/Projects/test/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/json-2.6.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (2.6.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '2.6.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  cocoapods was resolved to 1.12.1, which depends on
    cocoapods-core was resolved to 1.12.1, which depends on
      algoliasearch was resolved to 1.27.5, which depends on
        json
✖ Installing Ruby Gems
error Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=android and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Comment: Try `gem install ffi`, or manually installing the gem it fails on (`gem install json`). It could also help to post the contents of the log mentioned in the error.